# Adding commas to java.net.URL

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to run a query on Elasticsearch's /_cluster endpoint.

I would like to do the following:

```
https://<my cluster>/_cluster/state/version,master
```

However, when I am getting a 403 response code.

Previously, I was using this logic to encode the string:

```
URL url = new URL(String.format(%s, %s, "myendpoint", "/_cluster/state/version,master"));
```

That did not work.

This also did not work:

`url = new URI(String.format("%s%s", "myendpoint", "/_cluster/state/version,master", null)).toURL();`

Is there a proper way to add commas to a java.net.URI?

EDIT: There were no problems with the URL.  For example, this would work:

```
        URL url = new URL(String.format("%s", " http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state/version%5C%2Cnodes"));

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
```

I had some proprietary signing code that was adding connection properties that was causing this to fail.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "did not work"? Also could you post your actual code (`String.format(%s, %s, ...)` can't even compile because first argument is not a string - is not in-between quotation marks `"`)

Comment: It turns out it was not an error with the comma.  I was adding some signatures to the connection that was causing the error.

Comment: In that case feel free to delete your question as in current state it doesn't even describe problem you ware really facing so others with same problem will most likely not be able to find your question (which is main goal of Stack Overflow). Or update your question and clarify it. Introduce [mcve] and post answer explaining what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use escaping to build your URL.comma = %2C

Answer (score 0):

I think this works to you:

```
final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";


String queryString = 
        "a=" + URLEncoder.encode("Frick&Frack", ENCODING) +
        "&b=" + URLEncoder.encode("New York", ENCODING) +
        "&c=" + URLEncoder.encode("US/Eastern", ENCODING) +
        "&d=" + URLEncoder.encode("when?", ENCODING) +
        "&e=" + URLEncoder.encode("20%", ENCODING) +
        "&f=" + URLEncoder.encode("#1", ENCODING);

URI uri = new URI("http", null, "example.com", -1, "/accounts", queryString, null);

System.out.println(uri);
```

Set encoding.